# I cannot play a sound twice in xaudio2

Tags: c++, directx, xaudio2

I am trying to set up xaudio2 and have been following the documentation. I can play a sound just fine, until I try playing it again, at which point nothing happens.
I have followed the documentation almost line for line, but can't figure out why this is happening.
here is the code.

```
        #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <xaudio2.h>
    #include <Windows.h>

    #ifdef _XBOX //Big-Endian
    #define fourccRIFF 'RIFF'
    #define fourccDATA 'data'
    #define fourccFMT 'fmt '
    #define fourccWAVE 'WAVE'
    #define fourccXWMA 'XWMA'
    #define fourccDPDS 'dpds'
    #endif

    #ifndef _XBOX //Little-Endian
    #define fourccRIFF 'FFIR'
    #define fourccDATA 'atad'
    #define fourccFMT ' tmf'
    #define fourccWAVE 'EVAW'
    #define fourccXWMA 'AMWX'
    #define fourccDPDS 'sdpd'
    #endif
    HRESULT FindChunk(HANDLE hFile, DWORD fourcc, DWORD& dwChunkSize, DWORD& dwChunkDataPosition)
    {
        HRESULT hr = S_OK;
        if (INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER == SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, NULL, FILE_BEGIN))
            return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());

        DWORD dwChunkType;
        DWORD dwChunkDataSize;
        DWORD dwRIFFDataSize = 0;
        DWORD dwFileType;
        DWORD bytesRead = 0;
        DWORD dwOffset = 0;

        while (hr == S_OK)
        {
            DWORD dwRead;
            if (0 == ReadFile(hFile, &dwChunkType, sizeof(DWORD), &dwRead, NULL))
                hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());

            if (0 == ReadFile(hFile, &dwChunkDataSize, sizeof(DWORD), &dwRead, NULL))
                hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());

            switch (dwChunkType)
            {
            case fourccRIFF:
                dwRIFFDataSize = dwChunkDataSize;
                dwChunkDataSize = 4;
                if (0 == ReadFile(hFile, &dwFileType, sizeof(DWORD), &dwRead, NULL))
                    hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
                break;

            default:
                if (INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER == SetFilePointer(hFile, dwChunkDataSize, NULL, FILE_CURRENT))
                    return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
            }

            dwOffset += sizeof(DWORD) * 2;

            if (dwChunkType == fourcc)
            {
                dwChunkSize = dwChunkDataSize;
                dwChunkDataPosition = dwOffset;
                return S_OK;
            }

            dwOffset += dwChunkDataSize;

            if (bytesRead >= dwRIFFDataSize) return S_FALSE;

        }

        return S_OK;

    }
    HRESULT ReadChunkData(HANDLE hFile, void* buffer, DWORD buffersize, DWORD bufferoffset)
    {
        HRESULT hr = S_OK;
        if (INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER == SetFilePointer(hFile, bufferoffset, NULL, FILE_BEGIN))
            return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
        DWORD dwRead;
        if (0 == ReadFile(hFile, buffer, buffersize, &dwRead, NULL))
            hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
        return hr;
    }


    class VoiceCallback : public IXAudio2VoiceCallback
    {
    public:
        void STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnStreamEnd() override
        {}
        void STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnVoiceProcessingPassEnd() override
        {}
        void STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnVoiceProcessingPassStart(UINT32 SamplesRequired) override
        {}
        void STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnBufferEnd(void* pBufferContext) override
        {
        
            std::cout << "buffer end" << std::endl;
        }
        void STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnBufferStart(void* pBufferContext) override
        {
            std::cout << "buffer start" << std::endl;
        }
        void STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnLoopEnd(void* pBufferContext) override
        {}
        void STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnVoiceError(void* pBufferContext, HRESULT Error) override
        {}
    };

    int main()
    {


        WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE wfx = { 0 };
        XAUDIO2_BUFFER buffer = { 0 };
        HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA(
            "meow.wav",
            GENERIC_READ,
            FILE_SHARE_READ,
            NULL,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            0,
            NULL);

        if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFile)
            return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());

        if (INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER == SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, NULL, FILE_BEGIN))
            return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());

        DWORD dwChunkSize;
        DWORD dwChunkPosition;
        //check the file type, should be fourccWAVE or 'XWMA'
        FindChunk(hFile, fourccRIFF, dwChunkSize, dwChunkPosition);
        DWORD filetype;
        ReadChunkData(hFile, &filetype, sizeof(DWORD), dwChunkPosition);
        if (filetype != fourccWAVE)
            return S_FALSE;
        FindChunk(hFile, fourccFMT, dwChunkSize, dwChunkPosition);
        ReadChunkData(hFile, &wfx, dwChunkSize, dwChunkPosition);
        //fill out the audio data buffer with the contents of the fourccDATA chunk
        FindChunk(hFile, fourccDATA, dwChunkSize, dwChunkPosition);
        BYTE* pDataBuffer = new BYTE[dwChunkSize];
        ReadChunkData(hFile, pDataBuffer, dwChunkSize, dwChunkPosition);
        buffer.AudioBytes = dwChunkSize;  //size of the audio buffer in bytes
        buffer.pAudioData = pDataBuffer;  //buffer containing audio data
        buffer.Flags = XAUDIO2_END_OF_STREAM; // tell the source voice not to expect any data after this buffer



        HRESULT hr;
        VoiceCallback vcb;

        // initialize COM
        if (FAILED(hr = CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINITBASE_MULTITHREADED)))
        {
            return hr;
        }

        // audio engine initialized to nullptr
        IXAudio2* audioEngine = nullptr;
        // initialize audio engine
        if ( FAILED(hr = XAudio2Create(&audioEngine, 0)))
        {
            return hr;
        }

        // create mastering voice
        IXAudio2MasteringVoice* masteringVoice = nullptr;
        // initialize masterVoice
        if (FAILED(hr = audioEngine->CreateMasteringVoice(&masteringVoice)))
        {
            return hr;
        }


        // create source voice
        IXAudio2SourceVoice* sourceVoice = nullptr;
        // init source voice
        if (FAILED(hr = audioEngine->CreateSourceVoice(&sourceVoice, (WAVEFORMATEX*)&wfx, 0u, 2.0f, &vcb)))
        {
            return hr;
        }
        // submit audio buffer to source voice
        if (FAILED(hr = sourceVoice->SubmitSourceBuffer(&buffer)))
        {
            return hr;
        }


        bool over = false;
        while (!over)
        {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState('S'))
            {
                over = true;
            }
            if (GetAsyncKeyState('M'))
            {


                if (FAILED(hr = sourceVoice->Start(0)))
                {
                    return hr;
                }
            

            }
            if (GetAsyncKeyState('A'))
            {
                sourceVoice->Stop();
            }
   
        }


        audioEngine->Release();
        audioEngine = nullptr;

        masteringVoice = nullptr;

        CoUninitialize();


    }
```

any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single XAudio2 source voice can only be playing or not playing. It can't be playing 'twice'. If you want the same sound with overlapping playback, you need to have two XAudio2 source voices active. You can submit the same audio to as many different format-compatible voices as you want. Remember that your audio data remains in your applications' memory, and each source voice just reads it directly from there (i.e. there's no copying of all the source data like there was in DirectSound).

XAudio2 is a 'real-time mixer' for complex sounds like you find in games. If you just want to play a WAV file, that's what the old Win32 `PlaySound` function did.

If you want to play the same sound again, you have to submit the audio packet again. If you do it repeatedly, it will keep looping.

Alternatively, you can set the loop-count when you play it to just reuse the same submitted packet over and over again.

> You should take a look at [DirectX Tool Kit for Audio](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Audio) for a simple XAudio2-based audio library. It supports 'one-shot' sounds like you are trying to do here, as well as looping sounds, voice-management, positional audio, environmental effects, file-based streaming, etc.

Comment: I am not trying to play a 2 sounds at the same time. I am trying to play a sound twice over any period of time, once I play the sound, I can no longer play the sound at all.

Comment: @Jaden - you didn't set a loop count, so once the submitted packet completes the voice no longer has any data to play. You have to call ``SubmitSourceBuffer`` to queue it again.

Answer (score 1):

Seems no one was able to answer that question correctly. What the OP asked was about how to play the same sound twice, he meant that after playing the requesting the sound to play again after it has played, the sound didn't do anything.

That happens because Stop actually means "Pause" on XAudio2, for Stop actually resetting the sound position, you must call `IXAudioSourceVoice2::FlushSourceBuffers()`

This will reset the sound position to 0, so, for actually playing the sound more than one time, follows the code:

```cpp
void playSource(IXAudioSourceVoice2 voice, XAUDIO2_BUFFER* buffer)
{
    //Playing again without stopping is invalid on XAudio2
    voice->Stop(0); //Or use XAUDIO2_PLAY_TAILS for playing the reverb's tail
    //Remove the buffers and reset the audio position
    voice->FlushSourceBuffers();
    //Submit the buffer after the reset
    voice->SubmitSourceBuffer(buffer, null);
    //Play
    voice->Start(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop the audio then setup the buffer like this
you can pass (void*)&over as the context.
Then inside of the voice call back do something like

```
bool *myContext = (bool*)pBufferContext; 

*myContext = true;
```

to exit the loop. keep in mind that if loop_count = XAUDIO2_LOOP_INFINITE, then the voicecallback function OnBufferEnd(...) is not called

if you group the interfaces and related data in a structure or class you can pass them between functions. keep the interfaces until you absolutely dont need them anymore and no need to CoInitialize or CoUnintialize more than once for the lifetime of the app.

```
class my_xaudio_implement
{
    private: // data and interfaces
     
     bool ready_to_play = false;

     bool using_wfmt_ex = false;

     UINT32 xa_fill_pos = 0;

     BYTE *xa_data = NULL;

     // SAMPLE_STRUCT *xa_samples = NULL; // used to generate 2 channel samples

     UINT32 xa_data_size = 0; // data size in bytes

     UINT32 xa_data_samples; // data size in samples

     HANDLE xa_fhandle = NULL;

     WAVEFORMAT xa_wfmt = { 0 };

     WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE xa_wfmt_ex = { 0 };

     XAUDIO2_BUFFER xa_buffer = { 0 };

    IXAudio2 *ifc_audio_engine = NULL;
    IXAudio2MasteringVoice *ifc_master_voice = NULL;
    IXAudio2SourceVoice *ifc_source_voice = NULL;

    public: // functions, constructor/destructor

    bool xa_over = false; // this data object needs to be public

    VoiceCallback my_voice_cb();

    // constructor
    my_xaudio_implement( /* parameters */ )
    {
      // create xaudio engine

      // open the file or create the buffer and generate the wave data

      // create and fill the buffer { xa_data = (BYTE*)new BYTE[xa_data_size]; } 

      // xa_samples = (SAMPLE_STRUCT *)xa_data;
      
      // generate a wav file example snipet
      // for (UINT32 t = 0; t < Samples_To_Add; ++t)
      // { 
      //   if (xa_fill_pos == xa_data_samples) { break; } 
      //   xa_samples[xa_fill_pos].left  = amp_lt * sin(((freq_lt * t) + phase_lt) * radian);
      //   xa_samples[xa_fill_pos].right = amp_rt * sin(((freq_rt * t) + phase_rt) * radian);
       // ++xa_fill_pos;
      // }

      // create the master voice

      // create the source voice

      ready_to_play = true;

      // optional auto play here
    };

    // destructor
    ~my_xaudio_implement()
    {
       // destroy voices in reverse order
       if (ifc_sorce_voice) { ifc_source_voice->DestroyVoice(); ifc_source_voice = NULL; }

       if (ifc_master_voice) { ifc_master_voice->DestroyVoice(); ifc_master_voice = NULL; }

       // release xaudio engine 
       if (ifc_audio_engine) { ifc_audio_engine->Release(); ifc_audio_engine = NULL; }

       // release memory
       if (xa_data) { delete xa_data; xa_data = NULL; } 

       // disable certain functions
       ready_to_play = false;
    };

    bool setup_xa_wfmt( /* my parameters*/ );

    bool setup_xa_wfmt_ex( /* my parameters */ );

    // example parameters to use
    bool setup_xa_buffer(UINT32 sample_size = 0, UINT32 loop_count = XAUDIO2_LOOP_INFINITE, void *context = (void*)&xa_over);

    bool play(UINT32 sample_size = 0, UIN32 loop_count = XAUDIO2_LOOP_INFINITE, void *context = (void*)&xa_over);

    // optional loop, not needed if there is a main loop
    bool play_wait();
};

bool my_xaudio_implement::setup_xa_buffer (UINT32 sample_size, UINT32 loop_count, void *context) 
{

// sanity check
if (ifc_source_voice == NULL) { return false; }

if ((sample_size == 0) || (sample_size >= xa_sample_size)) { sample_size = xa_sample_size; }

xa_buffer.pAudioData = xa_data; // actual buffer
xa_buffer.AudioBytes = xa_data_size; // buffer size

xa_buffer.Flags = XAUDIO2_END_OF_STREAM;
xa_buffer.LoopBegin = 0;
xa_buffer.LoopCount = loop_count; // number of loops
xa_buffer.LoopLength = 0; //entire buffer
xa_buffer.pContext = context; // user defined pointer which is used in the callbacks
xa_buffer.PlayBegin = 0;  // buffer offset to start playing, 0 = begining
xa_buffer.PlayLength = sample_size; // 0 = play the entire buffer 

if (FAILED(ifc_source_voice->SubmitSourceBuffer(&xa_buffer))
{
  // error message

  return false;
}

return true;

}

bool my_xaudio_implement::play(UINT32 sample_size, UINT32 loop_count, void *context)
{
  if (!ready_to_play) { return false; }

  // sanity check since trying to using a NULL interface can crash the app
  if (ifc_source_voice == NULL) { return false; }

  if (!setup_xa_buffer(sample_size, loop_count, context)) 
  { 
    // error message

    return false; 
  }
  
  if (FAILED(ifc_source_voice->Start(0, XAUDIO2_COMMIT_NOW)))
  {
    //error message

    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

so now you create my_xaudio_implement myobj();

every time you execute myobj.play(0, 0, (void*)&xa_over) the buffer is resubmitted

executing myobj.play(); will execute with the default parameter values (entire buffer, infinite loop, context = &xa_over)

The destructor will cleanup the interfaces when the object goes out of scope.

if you create my_xaudio_implement *myobj = NULL; myobj = new my_xaudio_implement();
then just execute { if (myobj) { delete myobj; myobj = NULL; } } to perform the cleanup